# UILabel not updating - need to update AFTER fetchProducts completes

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

This is probably a really simple one.  The issue I am having is I am trying to execute a fetch products method to get the IAP from Appstore Connect, with the intention of then displaying the IAP details like price on the screen through a label.  The challenge is the label is being displayed before the fetch products method completes and therefore doesn't give me the results I am after.  If I try and assign the converted string of pricing to my labelNo3 then I get a runtime warning/error saying Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UILabel setText:] .

The runtime error/warning is coming from the productRequests method (see code below).  I looked at many examples and it suggested I wrap code in the DispatchQueue.main.async command - however it doesn't fix the issue.

I have tried to use the DispatchQueue.main.async command too but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

I'm using Xcode13 / Swift 5.  I've added the key code blocks below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Have to add ourselves as the delegate for payments
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        
        fetchProducts()
        
        loadTheEnvironmentalDBItems()
        checkTheEnvironmentals()
        
        // Even with the 2 lines below (commented out) it makes no difference)
        // let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "update")
        // queue.async {
            
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            print("L157: Should have finished getting the fetch info before executing")
            self.setupTheUI()
        }
        //}
        
    }

.
.
.

func setupTheUI() {
        // Setup the items on the scene ie. buttons, labels, images, however need to also add the pricing labels,
        // however we can't do that here as we need to do it after the fetch products is executed - so will call from
        // within fetch
        addButtonsToScene()
        setupTheGraphicImage()
        setupLabelNo1()
        
        setupTheFirstSubscriptionButton(buttonName: mySubscription1Button)
        setupTheSecondSubscriptionButton(buttonName: mySubscription2Button)
        setupLabelNo2()
        
        showMyPrivacyButton(buttonName: myPrivacyButton)
        showMyTermsOfUseButton(buttonName: myTermsOfUseButton)
        showMyRestorationButton(buttonName: restorePreviousPurchase)
        
        // Add actions to the buttons to monitor for key presses
        addActionToMyButton1()  // Privacy Policy
        addActionToMyButton2()  // Terms of Use
        addActionToMyButton3()  // Restore
        
        // Add actions to the subscription buttons
        addActionToSubscription1Button()
        addActionToSubscription2Button()
        
        // Add the pricing to the scene for the subscriptions (noting you need
        // fetchproducts method to complete first, however it seems the method below is
        // being called before fetchproducts completes meaning the label.text is
        // wrong
        setupTheSubscriptionNo1PriceLabel()

    }
.
.
.

func setupTheSubscriptionNo1PriceLabel() {
        // Note: This has to be called after fetch products in order to get the pricing for the subscription from
        // Apples App Store Connect first.  Doing this so that I can support localised pricing.
        print("L:357 - Setting up the price label for subscription 1")
        
        // Set the coordinates for the label inside the box
        subscriptionNo1PriceLabelX = (subscription1ButtonX + 160) / 2
        subscriptionNo1PriceLabelY = subscription1ButtonY + 100
        
        labelNo3.numberOfLines = 1
        labelNo3.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue", size: 34.0)
        labelNo3.textColor = .white
        labelNo3.center = CGPoint(x: subscriptionNo1PriceLabelX, y:subscriptionNo1PriceLabelY)
        labelNo3.textAlignment = .left
        labelNo3.text = subscriptionNo1PricingLabel
        view.addSubview(labelNo3!)
        
        print("Label No3 is: \(labelNo3.text!)")
        print("SubscriptionNo1PricingLabel is currently: \(subscriptionNo1PricingLabel)")
        
    }
.
.
.

func fetchProducts() {
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(Product.allCases.compactMap({ $0.rawValue })))
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
    
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    
        mySubscriptions = response.products
        var myProduct = mySubscriptions[0]
        
        print("L630: Count of products on Apple App Store Connect is \(response.products.count) (of 2 hopefully)")
        
        // This converts the price for subscription 1 from Decimal to String
        subscriptionPriceDecimal = myProduct.price as Decimal
        subscriptionNo1PricingLabel = amountFormatted
        labelNo3.text = subscriptionNo1PricingLabel
        
        print("L640: The subscription price for subscription #1 is \(amountFormatted)")
        print("L641 SubscriptionNo1PricingLabel is \(subscriptionNo1PricingLabel)")
        
        
        // This converts the price for subscription 2 from Decimal to String
        myProduct = mySubscriptions[1]
        subscriptionPriceDecimal = myProduct.price as Decimal
        subscriptionNo2PricingLabel = amountFormatted
        print("L647: The subscription price for subscription #2 is \(amountFormatted)")
    }
```

NOTE: There is nothing unusual about my fetch products method, that just works so I haven't included the code.  However the issue is the UILABEL is being shown before the fetch products method completes.  This means I am unable to display the pricing of the subscriptions that I've configured on Appstore Connect.

I've just added the fetch / productRequest methods above also.  The issue that I am trying to solve for is that I get a warning / error at runtime of Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UILabel setText:].  This is being caused by the line in the productsRequest method:

labelNo3.text = subscriptionNo1PricingLabel

This is why I think I need to use the
DispatchQueue.main.async command in order that I can update labelNo3.

Also, I've includes some of the console print screen stuff so you can see what is going on:

```
INT Marker: [L81] - SUBSCRIPTIONS SCENE - viewDidLoad
L157: Should have finished getting the fetch info
Subscription 1 Button X = 13.75 and Y is 230.0
L:357 - Setting up the price label for subscription 1
Label No3 X: 86.875
Label No3 Y: 330.0
Label No3 is: 22
SubscriptionNo1PricingLabel is currently: 22


INT Marker: [L158] - SUBSCRIPTIONS SCENE - viewWillAppear

L630: Count of products on Apple App Store Connect is 2 (of 2 hopefully)
L640: The subscription price for subscription #1 is $0.99
L641 SubscriptionNo1PricingLabel is $0.99
L647: The subscription price for subscription #2 is $9.99
```

Thus you can see that the correct pricing is being brought back (is displayed in the console from code executed within the fetchproducts / productsRequest method...  However you can see from the first block that the label is being setup / completing prior to fetchproducts despite fetchproducts being called earlier in viewdidload....

Help?  Thoughts?  And Thanking all in advance for sensible answers... and yes I have looked through stack overflow for similar issues but haven't found a fix yet (sorry just had to say that so that I don't get referred to some article from 2017 when it doesn't apply to my situation above).....

Comment: can you show that code of fetchProducts

Comment: Hi Karthik, as requested I've added the fetch and productsRequest methods, also with a little more info about where things are going wrong, ie. it's all to do with trying to set the labelNo3 within productsRequest which seems to be the issue... however I am struggling to resolve the issue.... hope this helps... again thanking you in advance for taking the time to look at the above and offer any insight at all... if not then thanking you anyway for taking the time to read the above. cheers James.

Answer (score 0):

Ok folks, I have answered my own question and solved it (can't believe it's taken me a few hours though)... Anyhow, I modified the productsRequest method and inserted the DispatchQueue.main.async command around the offending line of code (the code whereby I was trying to assign a converted Decimal string of price to my labelNo3.text), and it seems to have done the trick.  I no longer get the runtime warning/errors...  The actual code is:

mySubscriptions = response.products
var myProduct = mySubscriptions[0]

```
    print("L630: Count of products on Apple App Store Connect is \(response.products.count) (of 2 hopefully)")
    
    // This converts the price for subscription 1 from Decimal to String
    subscriptionPriceDecimal = myProduct.price as Decimal
    subscriptionNo1PricingLabel = amountFormatted
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
        self.labelNo3.text = subscriptionNo1PricingLabel
    }
```

Again Thank you all to those who have looked and to Karthik above who responded earlier.  Thank you and Thank You stack overflow :)

Comment: I was just writing an answer and you beat me to it -- glad you figure it out. The issue as that the StoreKit request works *asynchronously*. That means that it is not guaranteed to finish at any specific time. So, the lines of code that you had directly after `fetchProducts* run the risk of (and were) getting executed before the async request is done. This is commonly avoided with a completion handler, which is essentially what the delegate function `productsRequest(_ request:` is functioning as.